# access values within custom eventargs class

Tags: c#, .net, events, delegates

Do I always need to use a delegate / Eventhandler to get to the data stored within a custom EventArgs class or can I access it directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A custom `EventArgs` class is just like any other class.  If you have an instance of it, you can access it's (visible) members.

Typically, however, `EventArgs` is only used in conjunction with events, and you need a delegate to subscribe to an event.  As such, it would normally be used (from the consumption side) with some form of delegate, though this could just be a delegate referencing a standard method where you use the `EventArgs` subclass.

Comment: can you answer this for me then specifically?? Am I getting an invalid cast for some other reason?             http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5405929/how-to-access-custom-eventargs-class-in-button-click-event

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can access a custom eventArgs class just like another class. I believe it needs to be within a Delegate that returns the data properly... I have tried to access the custom event args class directly from within any event (including a button) and it has been fruitless...

See my follow up question:

[how to access Custom EventArgs class in Button click event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5405929/how-to-access-custom-eventargs-class-in-button-click-event/5407069#5407069)