# how to access Custom EventArgs class in Button click event?

Tags: c#, .net, eventargs

As a follow up to:
[access values within custom eventargs class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5399770/access-values-within-custom-eventargs-class)

How do I access public variables within custom Eventargs class, using button click or any other method?

Example Custom Event Args class:

```
public class TraderEventArgs: EventArgs
{
    private int _shares;
    private string _symbol;

    public TraderEventArgs(int shs, string sym)
    {
        this._shares = shs;
        this._symbol = sym;
    } 

    public decimal Price 
    {
        get {return _prices;}       
    }

   public int Shares
   {
       get { return _shares; }
   }
}
```

Code behind button_click event:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // run trader app
        myApp.Main();

        // try to access TraderEventArgs class
        TraderEventArgs: EventArgs ev = TraderEventArgs: EventArgs();   // Invalid

        TraderEventArgs ev = new TraderEventArgs();   // this needs argument variables that are unassigned... ?

        TraderEventArgs ev = (TraderEventArgs)e;  //  Unable to cast object of type 'System.EventArgs' to type TraderEventArgs'.

        string sym = ev.Symbol.ToString();
        string sharws = ev.Shares.ToString();

        // do something with data

     }
```

thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the button click event is raised, it's creating the `EventArgs` that gets passed into "e".  That object was not created by you, but rather by the framework itself, and is of type `EventArgs`.  This prevents you from being able to cast it to a different type.

If you want to have an event that raises `TraderEventArgs`, you need to create an event, preferably of type `EventHandler<TraderEventArgs>`, and raise this event somewhere that is in your control.  This allows you to generate the class of the correct type, then handle it (in a separate event handler) directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that. The `EventArgs` of the `Click` event is always of type `EventArgs`; you can't expect it to be of type `TraderEventArgs`, because the event args is created by the button, and the button doesn't know anything about `TraderEventArgs`. The only way it could work is if you create your own `Button` control that raises the event with a `TraderEventArgs` instead of an `EventArgs`

Comment: then how is the information in TraderEventArg accessed from within a button click?  I don't care if the button eventargs knows anything about the data.  Is it impossible to get to?

Comment: why can't I do this ?                                public static TraderEventArgs ev = TraderEventArgs;              At top of page???

Comment: Well it depends, where does the TraderEventArgs come from? Where is it created?

Comment: For your second question: you need the `new` keyword to create an instance of an object: `public static TraderEventArgs ev = new TraderEventArgs();`. But it doesn't really make sense, why would you store an event arg in a static field? Event args are supposed to carry event data...

Comment: new TraderEventArgs(); wont work because TraderEventArgs references arguments not present when instantiating a class.  To get to the data you have raise and even corresponding to it or to an eventargs class that is not already embedded in the framework (I think, @Copsey below).

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Pass custom event args through a custom delegate and event that returns the data (Datatable, Array, etc)...using whatever button click or other event necessary.

So as a function of the delegate the correct data is returned.. I can not post the complete code here, but it is a modification of this very excellent example on event delegate usage...

Core C# and .NET
3.7. Delegates and Events
http://flylib.com/books/en/4.253.1.38/1/